# Is there an Easy way to enter a list of items into an Array, say 50-100?

Tags: java, arrays

I am trying to create an array with about 100 names. I want the names to be the ones I have selected not randomly generated ones. So each position of the Array will hold a string of a name. Is there an easier way to do this than `Array[1] = "name; Array[2] = "name";` ? The way I was thinking was to use a for loop to get the information from a data file or a text file but I have no idea how to do that. What is the easiest way to accomplish this task?

Comment: There are a ton of tutorials with ways to load data from files in Java; have you tried any of those?

Comment: Yeah but i guess the part that was confusing to me was the file location, it would always error out but i figured it out, anyways. How can i used this and make the array an instance variable? I made a method for it but i cannot declare it private in the method

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you have a file with one name by line:

```
public static String[] getArrayStringRandom() {
    try {
        List<String> list = new LinkedList<String>();
        FileReader fileReader = new FileReader("file.txt");
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(fileReader);
        for (String name; (name = in.readLine()) != null;) {
            list.add(name);
        }
        in.close();
        fileReader.close();
        // Collections.shuffle(list); // Random permutes
        return list.toArray(new String[0]);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
}
```

Comment: Vergas I can use this in the Main method, but how do i use it to create an instance variable. I am trying to write in this file and use the array as say an instance variable private String[] name; This executes it in the main method, is there a way to create it in just the class and use it as a variable?

Comment: You could create a static method that will return an array, something like `public static String [] getArrayString () { ... }`. Or you could create a static variable and put the reading of file  in the *static initialization block* `static { ... }`. See more in http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/initial.html

Comment: Okay i understand that, now what if i wanted to access specific numbered arrays in said string so if I want to do something like this
variable = getArrayString(); That is what i am allowed to do, I want to do variable = getArrayString().randomize, or even just pick out the String at array[1], is that possible from the getArrayString() Static method that you suggested?

Comment: Yes. If you want a element, only use `getArrayString()[1]`, although it will read the file again... It all depends on what you are allowed by your teacher.

Comment: That works perfectly I just had to add a throw/catch exception, that was the problem. Although it is quite tedious to do it 26 times for each switch statement. Thank you, you have been a huge help. And this is for a Final project, except I am adding a name randomization, that is not needed at all, but i wanted to do something cool.

Answer (score 2):

You can use an [*array initializer*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-10.html#jls-10.6):

> An array initializer may be specified in a declaration, or as part of an array creation expression, to create an array and provide some initial values. It is written as a comma-separated list of expressions, enclosed by braces `{` and `}`.

```
Array = new String[] {"name1", "name2", ..., "name100"};
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps like this. Reading it from a text file could work too but would require more effort although it would be more dynamic.

```
String[] myArray = {"Jon","Mike","Dave","Ed","Ted","Shirly","Jane","Robert"};//etc
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, if you already have all the names listed out in a text file then then parsing a txt file and populating the array is an efficient choice.

[Here is everything you will need to accomplish it.](http://www.javapractices.com/topic/TopicAction.do?Id=87)

If however you do not already have all the names listed out digitally (aka if you have them written down on a sheet of paper) and you know they will not change then just manually add them in the code.

A draw back of doing this however is if you ever need to update the list of names it is much easier to deal with a txt file rather than hard code.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to fill the array with hardcoded values, you can just use

```
String stringArray = new String[]{ "Name1", "Name2", ... };
```

If you want to retrieve it from a file as you suggest, you can use a loop similar to

```
String stringArray = new String[100];
for( int i = 0; i < stringArray.length; i++ ){
   stringArray[i]=retrieveNextValueFromFile();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to initialize an array would be:

```
String[] array = { "a", "b", "c", "d", "e" };
```

... But if you're planning to read the names from a file, you'll have to store it one by one:

```
List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
// ... read each name from the file
list.add(name);
// finally, convert the list to a String[]
String[] array = list.toArray(new String[list.size()]);
```

Answer (score 0):

If this is just for testing a homework assignment, you can use the `<` command-line tool to pass the file and a standard scanner.  Example

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Example {
  public static void main(String[] args){
    Scanner cin = new Scanner(System.in);
    String[] stringArray = new String[100];

    for(int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
      stringArray[i] = Scanner.nextLine();
  }
}
```

Now if you have a file (filename.txt) that contains the name on each line, call the program from the cprompt with:
`java Example < filename.txt`

This is good for testing...